# Git error : RPC failed

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a problem when i try to make a git pull / git push or even git clone. The error is always the same : "error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504".

I tried some solutions that google gave me, but the error seems not common. (in fact, RPC failed; result=22 is common, but with an other HTTP error code)
I also tried to take the last git version and clone the repository unsuccessfully tory with no success.

Moreover, this error occurs only on 1 repository (other are ok), and on my laptop (desktop tower works fine).

Does someone know more about it ?

Comment: If you run `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git pull` on the repo in question and from the laptop, then it may provide additional detail. I suspect this is a timeout issue, though.

Comment: This Http code is a time out. I made a repair system and it works now.